# Comparasion of numbers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm stuck at this. I`m beginner into software development.
You get a list of N students and then a list of ratings for each student. A student which has bigger rating than his neighbour from list gets more candies than both of them. For example:

Data input:

- 3
- John
- Michael
- Sam
- 9
- 10
- 8

Data Output:

- John 1
- Michael 3
- Sam 1

I wrote this code, but I'm missing something:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO.Pipes;
{
   int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   string[] studentsList = FillArray(number);
   int[] studentsGrades = ConvertList(FillArray(number));
   PrintResult(studentsList, CountCandies(int number));
}

static string[] FillArray(int number)
{
   string[] result = new string[number];
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       result[i] = Console.ReadLine();
   }

   return result;
}

static int[] ConvertList(string[] array)
{
   int[] result = new int[array.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
   {
       result[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
   }

   return result;
}

static int[] GetGrades(int number) // give grades of each student
{
   int[] result = new int[number];
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       result[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   }

   return result;
}

static int CountCandies(int[] arr, int number) // this is the method where I'm stuck.
{
   int sum = 0;
   int[] ans = new int[number];

   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       ans[i] = 1;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < number-1; i++)
   {
       if (arr[i+1] > arr[i])
       {
           ans[i+1] =ans[i] +1;
       }
   }

   for (int i = number-2; i>=0; i--)
   {
       if (arr[i] > arr[i+1] && ans[i] <= ans[i+1])
       {
           ans[i] = ans[i+1] +1;
       }

       sum += ans[i];
   }

   sum += ans[number-1];

   return sum;
}

static void PrintResult(string[] array, int[] array2) // print the final result
{
   for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
   {
       array[i] += " " + array2[i];
   }

   foreach (string student in array)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(student);
   }
}
```

Comment: You know what you want: a Student _object_, not arrays of each thing.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need an object to hold your data.

```
public class StudentRating
{
 public string StudentName {get;set;}
 public int Rating {get;set;}
}
protected List<StudentRating> studentsRating = new List<StudentRating>();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  GeteringInformation();
  //after this do what you want with your data
}
protected static GeteringInformation()
{
 Console.WriteLine("Student name:");
int rating =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Rating");
string name =Console.ReadLine();
studentsRating.Add(new StudentRating(){StudentName=name,Rating=rating});
Console.WriteLine("Next? (Y/N)");

if(Console.ReadLine().ToLower()="y")
  GeteringInformation();

}
```

Comment: The (Y/N) method can be replaced? I don't want to insert another inputs than that from problem's statement.

Comment: If you remove this than u will insert only 1 student , it's for looping your console for imputing as many students as you need